# Existence of an element that satisfies specific order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Consider a group $G$ such that $|G| = 12 = 12 \times 1 = 4 \times 3 = 6 \times 2$.

We know that the order of any subgroup must divide the order of the group by Lagrange's Theorem.

Since

1. $12 \mid 12$
2. $1 \mid 12$
3. $4 \mid 12$
4. $3 \mid 12$
5. $6 \mid 12$
6. $2 \mid 12$

It is natural to ask if we can find an element $g_d \in G$ such that $ord(g_d) = d$ where $d$ is any divisor of $12$.

It is clear that there's an element $g_1$ with order $1$, namely the identity of $G$. From Cauchy's theorem we can also get $g_2$ and $g_3$. Moreover, $12 = 2^2\times3$ so there's an element $g_4$ of order $4$ from Sylow's Theorems.

We're left to find a non-trivial element of order $12$ and another of order $6$. I wonder if there are any theorems that guarantee the existence of such elements.

Thanks.

Comment: Sylows theorem does not guarantee element orders, just subgroup orders. (E.g. $A_4$ of order 12 has no element of order 4.) Basicaly, unless your group is cyclic, the only thing you can guarantee from the group order are prime order elements.

Comment: @ahulpke So, in this case we can only guarantee the existence of elements $g_2$ and $g_3$ from Cauchy's. And we don't know anything about the existence of the following elements: $g_4$,$g_6$ and $g_{12}$?

Comment: $g_{12}$ does not exist in general, except for $G\cong C_{12}$. For the other four groups of order $12$ there is no element of order $12$ - see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_12).

Comment: $A_4$ neither has elements of order $4$ nor $6.$

Comment: @AnneBauval That sentence does not make sense! You need the word "neither" to go with "nor": "$A_4$ has elements of order neither $4$ nor  $6$" or better: "$A_4$ has neither elements of order $4$ nor of order $6$".

Comment: I neither believe s.o. won't understand nor will misunderstand my sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Cauchy's theorem, you can guarantee elements of orders $2$ and $3.$ Every group has an identity, so it has an element of order $1.$ The group $A_4$ only has elements of orders $1, 2,$ and $3.$